# Allow Linux to connect with addresses containing domains with dash followed by dot

Tags: dns

I can't connect with addresses containing domains with dash followed by dot, for example:

```
http://example-.domain.tld/
```

The only solution I found for this is adding domains like those to /etc/hosts, but I don't know all of those, so I can't do it.

I know this is out of standard, but Windows allows addressing like this and I have to implement it also under Linux.

System info:
Fedora 20, linux 3.12.5-302
Tested under Firefox, Opera

I tested real-life, public internet domain and dig is working proper but ping is not.

Comment: You need to provide more info, such as what you're using to test. Is this a browser, some utility, what? That exact host name works perfectly fine on my system: http://i.imgur.com/FucBp8a.png

Comment: Thansks for reply. I've added needed info.

Comment: Since [RFC 952](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952) does not allow hostnames to end with an hyphen (and neither does [RFC 1123](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123)), I'd say this is standard-related. In your case, the `example-` subdomain could be considered invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you out of luck with that, because linux libc doesn't support this. Your only options is to change glibc or rebuild your software against some alternative C library.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4671

You could also override gethostbyname with some ld-preloaded library of your own and provide your own resolution method there. This was you'll have no need to build anything.